# Problem with running code and linking parts

Tags: python, if-statement, input, while-loop, menu

```
def menu():
    print("1. Create new User")
    print("2. View User")
    print("3. Update User")
    print("4. Quit ") 
menu()

selection=input("Select a menu- Input a number:")

if not selection.isdigit():
    print("You have input a non digit value. Select again:")
    selection=input("Select a menu- Input a number:")
else:  
    selection = int(selection)
    if selection==1:
      print("::menu 1::")
      newName = input("Input first name : ")
      newSurname = input("Input last name : ")
    elif selection==2:
      print("::menu 2::")
    elif selection==3:
      print("::menu 3::")
    elif selection==4:
      print("you have logged out")
    else:
      print("There is no menu",end=" ")
      print(selection)
      print()
      menu()
      selection=input("Select a menu- Input a number:")
```

so when i run the code and input a wrong value first (non integer) then input a number that's not in the menu i want it to be able to let me to then input another number like a right one eg 1 but its seems it doesn't do anything after that and i don't know how to fix it can someone help. It only acknowledges 1-4 only when i do it first but not after any wrong values.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a loop to verify input. Breaking the loop and continuing when the user inputs something valid.

```
selection=int(input("Select a menu- Input a number:"))
while selection not in (1,2,3,4):
    selection=int(input("Invalid number...Select a menu- Input a number:"))
```

Note that this will throw an error if something other than an integer is input. If you want to handle that you should use a `try` statement.

Comment: It would be best to wrap this up in a function.

Comment: @Chris agreed. There are definitely a few improvements that could be made to improve usability/control flow. The entire `else` block in the question should be a function, too. I figured it might be best to start OP off with a very bare-bones example.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this did not happen is because you should wrapp the entire menu, in a while loop. If the entered number is not in the menu, then it'll just display one more time the menu by calling `menu()`, then it'll ask you to insert one more number `selection=input("Select a menu- Input a number:")`, and then, it stops running. There is not other instruction to execute next.

```
def menu():
    print("1. Create new User")
    print("2. View User")
    print("3. Update User")
    print("4. Quit ") 
menu()
selection=input("Select a menu- Input a number:")
while selection != 4:    
    if not selection.isdigit():
        print("You have input a non digit value. Select again:")
        selection=input("Select a menu- Input a number:")
    else:  
        selection = int(selection)
        if selection==1:
            print("::menu 1::")
            newName = input("Input first name : ")
            newSurname = input("Input last name : ")
        elif selection==2:
            print("::menu 2::")
        elif selection==3:
            print("::menu 3::")
        elif selection==4:
            print("you have logged out")
            break
        else:
            print("There is no menu",end=" ")
            print(selection)
            print()
            menu()
            selection=input("Select a menu- Input a number:")
```